# Gradle - Retrieve artifacts from FTP

Tags: maven, ftp, gradle

I have the a repository as the following one, where I upload my own artifacts:

```
repositories {
// ...

    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'pass'
        }
        url "ftp://server/maven2/"
    }
}
```

Trying to get artifacts from this results in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'ftp' not registered.`.

Is there a way I can use `ftp` repos in my gradle config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't supported. See [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_ignores_custom_maven_repository_ftp). FTP works only for deployment.

Comment: Apparently I have to publish the FTP structure over HTTP, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gradle 2.7 logs the following Error on my setup:

> Error: Not a supported repository protocol 'ftp': valid protocols are
>   [file, http, https, sftp, s3]

so i guess you have to setup a supported protocol in your environment